# I'm looking for a motherboard that allows to physically deny BIOS flashing

Tags: motherboard, security, upgrade

I'm looking for a motherboard that allows to physically deny BIOS flashing.

I want to buy a motherboard that only allows flashing an update to the bios if there is a physical jumper plugged in it, but i am having a lot of trouble after asking that on goggle, no useful results.

I think such facility would be a great security option, so i wont buy another desktop pc or notebook until i find it.

Linked:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669930/how-to-determine-what-chip-wire-allows-bios-flashing

Comment: I don't remember anything like it, but maybe there are some server boards or older boards that do allow for that